# Folder not detected in spite of its creation, when counted in the same button click event

Tags: java, android, file-io, android-mediascanner

I have an android activity, wherein a folder gets generated *within a button click*, along with some files within the folder.  Now I am trying to programmatically get the count of the number of files in that folder. My algorithm is somewhat like this:

```
 onClick()
 {
    createFolder();
    createFilesWithinFolder();
    countFilesInFolder();
 }
```

In this case, when I try to count the files using *countFilesInFolder()*, it gives zero in spite of the fact that the folder and the files are actually successfully created.

But if I do this instead and press the second button after the first,

```
   onClick1()
 {
    createFolder();
    createFilesWithinFolder();
 } 

 onClick2()
 {
    countFilesInFolder();
 }
```

It counts the number of files properly. Later when I checked my countFilesInFolder() function, I came to know that it was not detecting the creation of the folder itself, and hence everything was giving zero.

I tried using the following media scanner class to overcome this issue, but it did not work:

```
  class SingleMediaScanner implements MediaScannerConnectionClient 
{ 
    private MediaScannerConnection mMs; 
    private String mPath; 
    SingleMediaScanner(Context context, String f) 
    { 
        mPath = f; 
        mMs = new MediaScannerConnection(context, this); 
        System.out.println("Commencing connection");
        mMs.connect(); 
    } 
    @Override 
    public void onMediaScannerConnected() 
    { 
        //mMs.scanFile(mPath, null); 

          mMs.scanFile(mPath, null);
        Log.i("SCANNER","Scanning :"+mPath);
    } 

          @Override
          public void onScanCompleted(String arg0, Uri arg1) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Log.i("SCANNER","Media Scan Completed");
                 mMs.disconnect(); 

          }

}
```

I require that the file creation and counting  must both occur in the **Same** button click as I have illustrated in my first algorithm. How should I do this? Please assume that the *pseudo-functions* I have mentioned above are all correct, as I have seen it working properly in my second algorithm.